# Eclipse 2022-06 startup problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

There are some problems for using Eclipse 2022-06/03 on Ubuntu 22.04.

The below eclipse image is using this version:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/rc1/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers

The startup splash picture is not centered in the screen.

[image]

Why does eclipse can't put the startup picture on the center? Is it a BUG of eclipse or is it related to unknown packages missing on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Eclipse 2022-06 has not been released yet.

Comment: The 2022-06 has a RC1 release, I have added the link in the post. And 2022-03 has the same problem running on Ubuntu 22.04. But eclipse has no problem running on Ubuntu 20.04. There must be something wrong but I can't sure if it is related to Eclipse or Ubuntu.

Comment: RC means release candidate, not release. Eclipse uses SWT which is based on Linux on GTK. I would guess it is a change in GTK that causes this glitch. Whatever, this shouldn't be a Stack Overflow question. [Report it to Eclipse SWT](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt) with the screenshot you get with the [latest integration build of the Eclipse SDK](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) and what GTK version you have, best with a patch.

Comment: Thanks for your information related to Eclipse SWT. I have just found this github link, it says trying to change the wayland to x11. But I don't know how to change wayland to x11, can you help? https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158

Comment: When you can reproduce the mentioned issue, please follow https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158#issuecomment-1142873959

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have found the solution for solving Eclipse problem running on Ubuntu 22.04. please see the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @howlger's reply, I solved the Eclipse problem on Ubuntu 22.04 by adding this environment variable:

```
export GDK_BACKEND=x11
```

And then start eclipse, now everything in Eclipse will back to normal.

The ubuntu system still use wayland.

Note that it requires to restart system first if the environment variable is not a global variable because it won't take effect if Eclipse has already run first. the export must be called before Eclipse run at the first time.

Comment: I upvoted you because this solved a totally different problem as the OP for me - that of random crash of the IDE.

Comment: Thank you! This was been driving me crazy for ages, both with random crashes and inability to detach editors and views. This fixes it!